# How to define the value of Scipy.sparse svds k

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, svd

Scipy.sparse svds How do we choose a suitable value for k, because numpy svds can determine the number of k by retaining 90% of the energy in the matrix, so how does Scipy.sparse svds choose k?